# Datatable inside tabview's second tab is not processing properly after the submit

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the Two tabs inside of Tabview.  I have seperate command button to submit Tab1 and Tab2.

After submitting the Tab1's Command button I am able to process the updated values to my bean for second/multiple times I could not find any difficulties to process it again and again

but I could not do the same in he Second Tab. Once I submitted the values then I could not process anything to the bean in the Second Tab. I included the Sample Xhtml and Bean code.

Note * : I have a parent class that is act as a Parent Managed Bean with the scope of  @GroupedConversationScoped

Sample Xhtml :

```
<p:tabView>

<p:tab id="firstTabDataTable">
  .... Some components related to tab1 ...
</p:tab>

<p:tab >
        <p:dataTable id="secondTabDataTable" var="secondTabDataTableVar" widgetVar="secondTabDataTableWidget"
                                rowIndexVar="rowIndexParent" 
                                value="#{managedParentBean.managedChildBean.secondDatatableList}" 
                                 emptyMessage="#{bundle['primefaces.dataTable.content.empty']}">

                                 <p:column> ... </p:column>

                                 <p:rowExpansion> </p:rowExpansion>

                                .... So on So components


                                 </p:dataTable>
<p:commandButton id="submit" process="secondTabDataTable" value="#{bundle['button.submit']}" styleClass="btn-secondary" actionListener="#{managedParentBean.managedChildBean.processSave}"
    update="secondTabDataTable"></p:commandButton>


</p:tab>

</p:tabView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The submit button does not process @this

Comment: Process = @this is working but the client side values going only until the parent class not to the child once I submitted I am facing this issue.

Comment: Does process="secondTabDataTable @this" change anything?